# Authenticate users using devise based table?

Tags: devise, laravel-5

I have a rails app that authenticate users via devise gem

What if I wanted to authenticate the users of rails app in another laravel 5 based app?

Would this be possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: no, but I think I will right my own guard and customise the attempt method